# Heroku deployment stalls with my rails app, any suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy an app to heroku. I'm running an ubuntu VM. I just had a lot of trouble getting postgres set up, but I think I'm good to go with that.

I've run

```
heroku create
```

and i've committed the most recent changed upon my master branch. When I run bundle install - everything is ok. And when I run

```
git push heroku master
```

Everything is smooth, including the installing of the gems. Until I reach the line

```
------> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
```

Everything stalls and I'm greeted with this message 15 minutes later

```
Timed out compiling ruby app (15 minutes)
```

for good measure here is my database.yml code

```
development:
   adapter: postgresql
   database: saasbook
   pool: 5
   password:
```

And here is my gem file

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'rails_12factor' , group: :production
gem 'pg'
gem 'saas-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'rake'
gem devise'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'rails_layout'
gem 'zxing'
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'rqrcode_png'

ruby "2.0.0"
```

The heroku deployment tutorial stated to insert the line ruby "2.0.0" after bundle install, and before the commit. I am currently running ruby 1.9.3 if that matters/ would have a conflict.

Any suggestions would be a huge help! thanks!

**Edit**

I'll leave this out here in case this problem ever arises again for someone
Alas, heroku doesn't like java/C dependent gems, and the QR decoding gem ZXING cannot be used on heroku, that was the reason it was stalling.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you're missing a quote in your Gemfile for `devise`:

`gem devise'` should be `gem 'devise'`

I would also recommend moving the `ruby "2.0.0"` line to the top of the Gemfile.  It may not matter, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a network issue. Be sure the network you are using has all the appropriate ports open for GIT and heroku. You will need more than port 80.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you solved this already but for ref:

Make sure that your IDE (mine is RubyMine) is not open on that project or the build will stall/fail.